# Stop Float at footer Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

Im using this code:

```
  $(window).scroll(function () {
  if (($(document).height() - $(window).scrollTop()) <= 500){
      $("#content-5").css({
          position: 'fixed',
          top: 'auto',
          bottom: '300px'
      });
  } else if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 30) {
      $("#content-5").css({
          position: 'fixed',
          top: '30px',
          bottom: 'auto'
      });
  }else{
      $("#content-5").css({
          position: 'absolute',
          top: '30px',
          bottom: 'auto'
      });
  }
```

});

And this is demo

> http://jsfiddle.net/Ym2Ga/75/

Its work fine, but i don't know how to do, that float elemnt stop at footer. Anyone can help?

Comment: What float element ?? the `#content-5` ?? Which part of footer ??

Comment: I think you need to use `<style>` and not  `$().css`.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Ym2Ga/75/ this is bad working fixed div. It's don't stop at footer, but should stop.

Answer (score 1):

I have updated you fiddle....change your first block of css as...

`$("#content-5").css({
     position: 'fixed',
     top: '0px',
     bottom: 'auto'
 });`

[fiiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ym2Ga/72/)

Comment: Did you check the `fiddle` i provided...? If yes then can you please explain what do you want to achieve...?