# Stop Float DIV at footer Jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I'm using this code:

```
 $(window).scroll(function () {
  if (($(document).height() - $(window).scrollTop()) <= 500){
      $("#content-5").css({
          position: 'fixed',
          top: 'auto',
          bottom: '300px'
      });
  } else if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 30) {
      $("#content-5").css({
          position: 'fixed',
          top: '30px',
          bottom: 'auto'
      });
  }else{
      $("#content-5").css({
          position: 'absolute',
          top: '30px',
          bottom: 'auto'
      });
  }
});
```

And this is demo

http://jsfiddle.net/Ym2Ga/75/

Its work fine, but i don't know how to do, that float div #content-5 stop at footer. Anyone can help?

Comment: Why do you want to float this div, as it is absolute/fixed?

Comment: Do you want #content-5 to disappear from the screen  along with the footer when you scroll further down ?

Comment: Yes singe31 disappear or stop above footer.

Comment: You asked this question before. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24980340/stop-float-at-footer-jquery

Comment: Thanks to all for solutions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this to `scroll()` Event:

```
  // if the bottom of #content-5 reached the top of the footer
  if($(window).scrollTop() > $("#footer").offset().top - $("#content-5").height()) {
       $("#content-5").css({
          position: 'absolute',
          top: $("#footer").offset().top - $("#content-5").height(), // Place it above the footer
          bottom: 'auto'
      });
  }
```

**demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Ym2Ga/82/**

Answer (score 0):

Here is your JSFiddle updated with the solution : http://jsfiddle.net/Ym2Ga/79/

The code :

```
    $(window).scroll(function () {
      var maxScroll = $(window).height()-$("#footer").height()-$("#content-5").height();
      if ($(window).scrollTop() >= maxScroll){
          $("#content-5").css({
              position: 'absolute',
              top: 'auto',
              bottom: '200px'
          });
      } else if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 30) {
          $("#content-5").css({
              position: 'fixed',
              top: '0px',
              bottom: 'auto'
          });
      }else{
          $("#content-5").css({
              position: 'absolute',
              top: '30px',
              bottom: 'auto'
          });
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get top offset of footer :

```
var footer_top= $("#footer").offset().top;
```

then u can check scroll if that is more than footer_top you should change your content css , like this :

```
$("#content-5").css({
              position: 'absolute',
              top: footer_top,//this is important for exact place 
              bottom: 'auto'
          });
```

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/Ym2Ga/81/)